# Set line width for default drawing functions in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to draw SIFT feature matches across two different pictures but when the image resolution is too high then the lines become barely visible (of course this is usually desired, and it is the expected behavior, and one can always zoom, but...). Is there a way to change default line width (or pass is as a flag) or is the only way to implement a custom drawing function?

Sample code for drawing:

```
img1 = np.array(Image.open("im1.jpg"))
img2 = np.array(Image.open("im2.jpg"))

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, desc1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, desc2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(desc1,desc2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x: x.distance)

out = np.concatenate([img1, img2], axis=1)
# Draw first 10 matches.
cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:20], flags=2, outImg=out)

plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))
plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think these are the flags: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d30/structcv_1_1DrawMatchesFlags.html

Maybe `flags=2|4` can help?

Comment: Sadly it does not, since I am drawing the lines between matching keypoints and not the keypoints themselves. I didn't know you can use multiple flags though, so thanks for that :)

Comment: You can't, the line width is hardcoded: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp#L53